# Timecomplexity analysis of function, Big O

Tags: algorithm

What time-complexity will the following code have in respect to the parameter size? Motivate.

```
// Process(A, N) is O(sqrt(N)). 

Function Complex(array[], size){
    if(size == 1) return 1;
    if(rand() / float(RAND_MAX) < 0.1){
        return Process(array, size*size)
             + Complex(array, size/2)
             + Process(array, size*size);
    }
}
```

I think it is O(N), because if Process(A, N) is O(sqrt(N)), then Process(A, N*N) should be O(N), and Complex(array, size/2) is O(log(n)) because it halves the size every time it runs. So on one run it takes O(N) + O(log(N)) + O(N) = O(N).

Please correct me and give me some hints on how I should think / proceed an assignment like this.

I appreciate all help and thanks in advance.

Comment: strange that the code does not return anything in 90% of the cases (assuming size > 1)...

Comment: What does the function return if `(rand() / float(RAND_MAX) >= 0.1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of the algorithm is `O(N)` indeed, but for a different reason.

The complexity of the function can be denoted as `T(n)` where:

```
T(n) = T(n/2)       +       2*n
        ^                   ^
      recursive          2 calls to 
      invokation        Process(arr,n*n),
                          each is O(n(
```

This recursion is well known to be O(n):

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 2*n = 
     = T(n/4) + 2*n/2 + 2*n = 
     = T(n/8) + 2*n/4 + 2*n/2 + 2*n
     = ....
     = 2*n / (2^logN) + ... + 2*n/2 + 2*n
     < 4n
     in O(n)
```

Let's formally prove it, we will use mathematical induction for it:

**Base:** T(1) < 4 (check)

**Hypothesis:** For `n`, and for every `k<n` the claim `T(k) < 4k`  holds true.

For `n`:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + n*2 = (*) 
     < 2*n + 2*n 
     = 4n
```

**Conclusion**: `T(n)` is in `O(n)`

(*) From the induction hypothesis